# How to keep Windows ListView Controls and the Objects they are mapped to in sync?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have several windows containing list view controls that map to the same array of objects. Everything works fine until I sort one of them. From what I understand, this changes the index of the item (despite trying to force iItem equal to the object member "id"). The problem is that if I delete a list view item after changing the default sort, it deletes the items in the other controls at the same position and also breaks the link between the object. For example, let's say the default 4 items I have is initially in the order A, B, C, D (in window 1 and window 2). I then re-sort the control in window 1 to D, C, B, A and delete B. In window 2, the item C will be deleted because it is in the same position.

I could loop through each item comparing the text, but that seems really inefficient. Is there anyway to map a ListView item to an internal id that does NOT change? If not, any ideas on how to make this work without jumping through too many hoops?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use LVITEM.lParam to give the item a unique id.  Or sort the collection instead.

Comment: Can you add an 'auxiliary' object pointer member to your ListItem class?  It's generally a bad idea to use ListItem indexes as indexes to anything else, 'cos they tend to change:(

Comment: @HansPassant LVITEM.lParam Of course! Thank you, that works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ListViews in virtual mode and have them all pull their data values from the same source array when requested.  If you need to sort/manipulate the ListViews individually, simply create separate arrays for each of them and have those arrays merely contain pointers (or indexes) to the elements of the main array.  You can then sort and delete items in each ListView array as needed, without affecting the other ListViews, and without wasting memory making copies of your source data everywhere.  Do not store your actual data in the ListViews themselves.

For example:

```
std::vector<std::string> MainData(4);
Main[0] = "A";
Main[1] = "B";
Main[2] = "C";
Main[3] = "D";
```

```
std::vector<int> ListView1Data(MainData.size());
for (int i = 0; i < ListView1Data.size(); ++i)
    ListView1Data[i] = i;

hListView1 = CreateWindowEx(..., LVS_OWNERDATA, ...);
ListView_SetItemCount(hListView1, ListView1Data.size()); 

...

case LVN_GETDISPINFO:
{
    NMLVDISPINFO* pdi = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(lParam);
    int index = ListView1Data[pdi->item.iItem];
    if (pdi->item.mask & LVIF_TEXT)
        strncpy(pdi->item.pszText, MainData[index].c_str(), pdi->item.cchTextMax);
    ...
    break;
}
```

```
bool CompareListItems(int a, int b)
{
    return MainData[a] < MainData[b];    
}

std::sort(ListView1Data.begin(), ListView1Data.end(), CompareListItems);
ListView_RedrawItems(hListView1, 0, ListView1Data.size());
```

```
ListView1Data.erase(ListView1Data.begin()+index);
ListView_SetItemCount(hListView1, ListView1Data.size());
```

If you want to delete an item in one ListView and have the same item be deleted in other ListViews regardless of their local sorting, you can do that as well:

```
int MainIndex = ListView1Data[index];

std::vector<int>::iterator iter = ListView1Data.begin()+index;
ListView2Data.erase(iter);
ListView_SetItemCount(hListView1, ListView1Data.size()); 

iter = std::find(ListView2Data.begin(), ListView2Data.end(), MainIndex);
ListView2Data.erase(iter);
ListView_SetItemCount(hListView2, ListView2Data.size()); 

iter = std::find(ListView3Data.begin(), ListView3Data.end(), MainIndex);
ListView3Data.erase(iter);
ListView_SetItemCount(hListView3, ListView3Data.size()); 

...
```

The trickiest part is if you need to remove the same item from the main array as well.  In which case, you have to update every ListView array with new pointers/indexes as needed.  In which case, it starts making sense to give each main array item a unique ID, and then keep track of that ID in each ListView array.  Then each ListView can look up the ID in the main array whenever it needs to access that item's data.

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time to write all that out for me. That's great as I was just thinking about how I need to get rid of all that redundancy. It's going to take me some time to digest the above, but I will surely let you know if it works out.

Comment: Read the documentation as a start: [Virtual ListView Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735.aspx#Virtual_ListView_Style) and [How to Use Virtual List-View Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh270411.aspx).

Comment: I haven't completely finished, but so far it seems to be working. However, the performance seems to be suffering (list view items taking more time to appear), which is counter-intuitive as I would expect it to be faster with the virtual list.

Comment: Virtual list views are VERY fast, so any slowdown to going to be related to how you are managing the data.  Use a profiler to find the bottlenecks.

Comment: Yes, it's working very fast now. I accidentally had some code logging to a file in LVN_GETDISPINFO, which was causing the slowdown.